# How to update kml file/layer dynamically?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-api, parcel

I am using a `kml` file for displaying map with custom boundary lines. That kml file is downloaded from some website. In that file, inside the `placemark` tag **there is no** `point` tag for display icons. Eg:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Spot 2</name>
    <description>.....</description>
    <styleUrl>....</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
    .........
    </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

That is the `placemark` tag contains. 1) How can I add `point` tag for all `placemark` tag. Is there any way to add dynamically? My kml file has 5000 and above placemarks. 2) Point tag coordinates will refers the center of the polygon.

i.e) I need the following

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Spot 2</name>
    <description>.....</description>
    <styleUrl>....</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
    .........
    </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>144.253,-36.6632,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Note:

Iam using geoxml3 parser to display kml layer in google map.